# Unable to get client ip address in aem access log

Tags: aem

I would like to know if there are any ways to get log the ip address of the client computer access the aem instance of pages within the aem project. The aem publish instance is currently hosted on a virtual machine with a dispatcher in place. Currently the logs are just displaying either 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 (ipv6) or 127.0.0.1 (ipv4).

The following image is an example of the access log captured. [Access Log Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo9KS.png)

I have tried to configure some settings within the aem dispatcher but to no avail. If you have encountered similar issues before, II would greatly appreciate for any help or sharing of applicable knowledge if you have encountered similar issues or previously attempted to solve similar problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You will always see the IP address of the dispatcher instance that is requesting the content from AEM.
Since most requests will not reach AEM anyway if there is a working and well configured dispatcher (and maybe a CDN as well) in place, it might make more sense to check the access logs of the webserver.

hth